# Problem in JDBC Connection Configuration/JDBC Request - JMETER

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm a problem in JDBC Connection Configuration.
When i execute my test (only JDBC Request - insert), doesn't appear any results in report (View Results Tree).

The connection is SQL Server.
See below the configuration:

- database URL: jdbc:sqlserver://${myURL}
- JDBC driver Class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
- Username: ${user}
- Password: ${password}

Could someone help me?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure to add [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter to pick up the .jar
2. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
3. Be informed that JDBC Connection Configuration is a [Configuration Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) hence [it's being executed before anything else](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) so your variables like `${myURL}`, `${user}` and `${password}` might not have their respective values yet
4. Check that your query returns results in [mssql-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli?view=sql-server-ver15)
5. Set the [validation query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978594/jdbc-validation-query) to `select 1` if it's different:

   [image]

You can check out [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article for more comprehensive steps if needed.